# route root to different controller if user is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We're using [devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) and are able to check if a logged in user is an admin in `routes.rb` so only admins can access `example.com/sidekiq`

```
authenticate :user, ->(user) { user.admin? } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web, at: '/sidekiq'
end
```

Is is possible to do something similar and point root to a different controller depending on whether a user is logged in or not like this pseudocode below?

```
if authenticate :user
  root "dashboard#main"
else
  root "pages#landing"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
authenticated(:user) do
  root "dashboard#main"
end

unauthenticated(:user) do
  root "pages#landing"
end
```

Using `unauthenticated` here is really optional. You could just define it as:

```
authenticated(:user) do
  root "dashboard#main"
end
root "pages#landing"
```

And take advantage of the fact that routes have priority in the order they are defined. But it does let you swap the order if you want to.

The difference between  `authenticate` and `authenticated` is that the former causes a authentication check and Warden will throw if the user is not authenticated so you get a redirect to the sign in page. `authenticated` will just not run the block if the user is not signed in.

See:

- [ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper](https://ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper)

Comment: both of the above gives the following error

`Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the ':as' option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with 'resources' as explained here: 
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't consider the clash between the helpers. You can use `root to: "dashboard#main", as: :authenticated_root` - or `get '/', to: "dashboard#main", as: :authenticated_root`.